# Spyder on Anaconda Windows 7 32-bit shows blank screen with menus

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I just install Anaconda 3 and Spyder 3.3.1. When I started Spyder for the first time it shows something like this:
[image: When i tried to open with Anaconda3/Scripts/Spyder.exe]

[image]
[image]

The problem is same with Windows 8.1.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please close Spyder, open an Anaconda Prompt, run there `conda install pyopengl` and try again.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba still the problem is change I added from from `OpenGL import GL` in the start.py but still it shows `QOpenGLShader::link: Failed to create D3D shaders.

Could not link shader program:
 "Failed to create D3D shaders.\n"
QOpenGLShader::link: Failed to create D3D shaders.
Failed to create D3D shaders.`

Comment: Then I think you need to update your graphics card drivers (Intel or Nvidia or both). Some people have told us that also has fixed the problem for them.

Comment: It works fine with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10.